# Are these two sets $\sigma$-algebras?

Tags: measure-theory

Set $A$ over $R := \{(−\infty, a], (a, b], (b, \infty), \emptyset, R, (a, b]\cup (b, \infty), (−\infty, a]\cup(a, b],(−\infty, a]\cup(b, \infty)\}$.

Set $B$ over $[0,10] := \{ [0,6],  [4,10],  \emptyset, [0,10], (4,6), [6,10], [0,4], [6,10] \cup [0,4] \}$.

They are both algebras, I think they are also $\sigma$ - algebras, but I am not 100% sure. They are closed under finite intersections. However, a countable set is either a finite set or a countably infinite set. so countable intersections implies finite intersections.

Comment: I took a look at your request.  If there are only finitely many members of an algebra, then countable intersections are really just finite intersections (repetitions are allowed but don't change the results of intersections).  Likewise any countable unions will amount to finite unions.  So when an algebra contains only finitely many elements, these will also be $\sigma$-algebras.  So you can proceed to answer whether the two collections of sets are $\sigma$-algebras by checking the simpler defining conditions to be algebras (of sets).

Comment: @hardmath Thanks for your reply!

Comment: In set $A$, are $a$ and $b$ fixed or are they allowed to vary over all choices of $a<b$?

Comment: @grand_chat I meant a and b are fixed and a < b, and $a,b \in R$.... thanks!

Comment: @grand_chat I think The set A is still a $\sigma$-algebra, for every choice of a<b.